# React native, how to stop infinitely running setInterval when a particular state variable value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native project I need to create a blinking (like warning) text. For this I use `setInterval` inside `useffect()` where I switch the text visibility by using `setShowText((showText) => !showText)`. Now I need to to stop the `setInterval` when another state variable `stopTriger` changes to `true`. (I have a sperate method to set `setStopTriger`).  Now the situation is like  `console.log('timer is running infinitely')`. How can I make it to work?  I use the following code, but not sure where to keep `stopTriger` condition:

```
const [stopTriger, setStopTriger] = useState(false)
const [showText, setShowText] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
// Change the state every second 

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setShowText((showText) => !showText);

  console.log('timer is running infinitely ')
// need to stop timer when stopTriger == true , how do I do it ?
   }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);

 }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `intervalID` in a state, and use another useEffect with `stoTrigger` as a dependency, when that variable is true, you can clear the interval:

**Update**

```
  const [interval, setStateInterval] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Change the state every second

    const interval_ = setInterval(() => {
      /* set value of interval state */
      setStateInterval(interval_);

      setShowText(showText => !showText);

      console.log('timer is running infinitely ');
      // need to stop timer when stopTriger == true , how do I do it ?
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (stopTrigger) clearInterval(interval);
  }, [stopTriger]);
```

Also, `clearInterval()` will automatically take care if the interval is currently running before clearing it, so you don't need to worry

Comment: Magic, that is working for me, when the `stopTriger==true' it stops.   Now, when the  `stopTriger` changes the state to `(' ')` it should blink after every `1` second, but  I see it blinks more frequently (after every 0.5 seconds). Do you also notice it ?

Comment: why `stopTrigger` changes to `'  '`? it should either be `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0):

stopTriger is initially false, and you aren't modifying it.

Comment: `clearInterval()` takes an interval `id`, `stopTriger` is a boolean